# A new site collection is for different users means different my-site in web application in sahrepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, sitecollection, mysite

I am new to sharepoint and working on already configured project.
A new site collection is created for a each user in my site.

I.e : http://mysite is my web application URL.
For news and about us section all going good. But whenever i Click on tasks link.
It will go to a new URL which is seems to be a new site collection URL.
So newly created site collection doesn't inherit the master page.

Is there is a way to stop this ? means to stop a new site collection creation for each users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is normal that new site collections are created for each user. It is used to store their Tasks list, their My Documents library, and other personal stuff.

If you want to prevent users from creating these site collections, you can deny them the right "Create Personal Site" in the User Profile Service (see this blog post for instance: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=222).
However you loose all related functionnality of course.

However these site collections should all use the same master page. So if your Sharepoint is not heavily customized, you can simple modify this masterpage.

Comment: Hey Matthieu, thanx for clarification on this. But these site collections however isn't using the same master page. I modify the master page on my account and its working but whenever a new creates mysite. This master page doesn't apply to their site. Please help...

Comment: How are you modifying your masterpage? I suggest you don't use Sharepoint Designer; this will modify your own masterpage only. Create a custom masterpage instead, and deploy it to your farm through a solution. Have a look at this article for instance: http://sharepointologic.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/branding-sharepoint-2013-my-sites-with.html